# How do I replay a users input with touchstart and touchend

Tags: javascript, arrays, touch-event

In my app a user can press 'start recording' which records this button

```
<div class="drum" id="bass" ontouchstart="play('bass');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Bass</div>
```

and then saves that information into an array

```
[{"time":918,"elemId":"bass"},{"time":1326,"elemId":"highhat"}]
```

How do I then replay this information into triggering the ontouchstart and ontouchend events? Basically mimicking the users input.

Comment: you should better call the functions rather than fake the events

Comment: How would I go about doing that exactly? I've tried everything it seems and it's just getting frustrating now

Answer (score 0):

You want something like ...

```
var NOTES=[{.....}],
    mCurrentNote=0,
    mStartTimer=0,
    mTimerId,
    mNextNote=null,
    SPEED=100; // speed in ms

// gets the next note

 function get_next_note() {
        return NOTES[mCurrentNote++] || null;
 }

 function timer() {
     // this gets called every SPEED ms
     if (mNextNote==null) mNextNote=get_next_note();
     if (mNextNode!=null) {
          var playhead=new Date.valueOf()-mStartTime;

          if (playhead < mNextNote.start) return;

          window.setTimeout(function() {play (mNextNote.type);},1);

     } else {
          window.clearInterval (mTimerId);
          // song finish
     }

 }

function playsong() {
    mCurrentNote=0;
    mStartTime=new Date.valueOf();
    mTimerId=window.setInterval (timer, SPEED);
}
```

However I'd recommend you to take a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/#toc-abstract if you plan to do something half-serious...